# How do i convert two int columns to a time(7) value in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm working on a project to update opening hours at a store chain and in the raw data i receive, hours and minutes are separated in 2 different columns as int values. for example:

**dbo.OpeningHoursRaw**

> OpeningHour | OpeningMinute | ClosingHour | ClosingMinute
>           10           |           0             |         17          |      
>   30

And i want to transform it to time(7) in a different table:

**dbo.OpeningHours**

> OpeningTime |
>          ClosingTime
>   10:00:00.0000000  |17:30:00.0000000

Do you have any suggestions on how i can do this using SQL query in MS SQL server managment studio?

Comment: Is MySQL involved here? (If not, please remove that tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql, use the MAKETIME method:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OpeningHours(OpeningTime, ClosingTime)
SELECT MAKETIME(o.OpeningHour,o.OpeningMinute,0) AS OpeningTime, MAKETIME(o.ClosingHour,o.ClosingMinute,0) AS ClosingTime
FROM dbo.OpeningHoursRaw o;
```

Or for SQL Server, use TIMEFROMPARTS:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OpeningHours(OpeningTime, ClosingTime)
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(o.OpeningHour,o.OpeningMinute, 0, 0, 0) AS OpeningTime, TIMEFROMPARTS(o.ClosingHour,o.ClosingMinute, 0, 0, 0) AS ClosingTime
FROM dbo.OpeningHoursRaw o;
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!